# PHP - Making table from JSON easily.

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a game, and the online scores are stored on a free server like www.sitename.subdomain.com/globalscore.txt.

The scores are stored in a json object, that has an array of json objects, each one contains the name, date, and the score of the player.
There are always 20 scores, and are always sorted.

Example

```
[{"scor":4290,"data":"17\/05\/14 15:30:58","nume":"MyName"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"},{"data":"-","scor":"1","nume":"Fainosag"}]
```

I want to make a page that will display the scores in a simple table, like

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="1" style="width:300px">
<tr>
 <td>Position</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Score</td>        

  </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
  <td>MyName</td>
  <td>4290</td>     

  </tr>
<tr>
 <td>2</td>
  <td>Fainosag</td>
  <td>1</td>        

  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]
With all 20 rows of course.
How can I do that?

Comment: Where are you stuck / Where are your attemtps to solving this?

Comment: `$data = json_decode($json_string,true);` then loop through data and display.

Comment: @jaykishan i'm not using jquery

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty how can i get the json string from the url and put it inside $data?

Comment: You can use `$json = file_get_contents('www.sitename.subdomain.com/globalscore.txt')`; if this does not work then use CURL to get the data.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like that :

I couldn't test this code though.

```
$json = file_get_contents("http://blabla.com/myJson.txt");

$scores = json_decode($json, true);

echo "<table>";
echo "<thead><td>Position</td><td>Name</td><td>Score</td></thead>";
$i = 0;
foreach($scores as $score){
    $i++;
    echo "<tr><td>$i</td><td>".$score['nume']."</td><td>".$score['scor']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: But if I have the json file on other ftp, how can i give $json the value of it? like www.xxx.xxxx.com/text.txt

Comment: Edited my answer to fetch the file from another server.

Comment: I only see Position Name Score ..

Comment: I used a wrong variable name, edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you are consuming the json object on server side using PHP then :

```
    $content = file_get_content("www.sitename.subdomain.com/globalscore.txt");
$data = json_decode($content);
    //loop on $data and print table $rows
    foreach($data as $item) {
      print '<tr>'. '<td>' .$item->scor.'</td>' .'</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: But where should I put my link to the server file?

Comment: I edited the snippet see file_get_contents

Comment: Why I get the error Fatal error: Call to undefined function file_get_content()  ?

Comment: use file_get_contents(url);

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /web/com/139781235711494/main.php on line 13

Comment: in the foreach loop use $item->scor instead of $item['score'] it is an stdclass so array notation won't work so use the arrow operator -> on each item

Comment: My code http://pastebin.com/05xVVfLC

Comment: see edited code above

Comment: 51234838483244414290428542774274414240954075407539923938393538753862367835653536 - this is what i see

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50948/discussion-between-xiarnousx-and-paul)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script> 
   $(document).ready(function(){
        // Fetch json object from server with AJAX and call updateTable(with json Object)


        function updateTable(jsonObj) {
            $(jsonObj).each(function(index, element){  
                $('#scores').append('<tr><td> '+element[0]+' </td> <td> '+element[1]+' </td> <td> '+element[2]+' </td></tr>');       
            })
        }
    });
</script>
<head>
    <body>
    .
    .
    <table id='scores' border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Position</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Score</td>
        </tr>
    <table>  
    .
    .
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Paul by using this method you will not need to call your server every time, you can directly modify the table from client side, with single call to `score server`